# What's with all of the low-quality Wall-e questions?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that since August 13th, there have been [ten Wall-e questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wall-e) with an average score of 0.1 each. Two have been closed. These are supposedly from seven different users but 6/7 are from now-deleted accounts.

What's happening here? Is a single person continually milling through accounts to ask questions that are mostly low/negative scoring?

Is there anything we should do about it?

Comment: Honestly I think the better question is *'Why all the hatred aimed at a set of largely reasonable on-topic questions, many of which are both interesting and answerable'*

Comment: It would appear that a single user is creating (and then disposing of) accounts in order to post these questions. Note that not all of the questions are "*low quality*". Several have quite a few upvotes (including a +6 and a +2) and most are pretty firmly on-topic, although the more recent ones have bordered on being opinion-based.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not going to go into specifics here about what is or isn't happening with these questions and accounts. The general rule of thumb is that we don't discuss other users or air dirty laundry.

That said if you find a pattern of behaviour or think something looks amiss you can report that behaviour to us mods for investigation. The general steps are [laid out here on main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66444/345161). I will say though that in cases like this, if you think there's something that needs further investigation please flag a relevant post and explain in the flag message what you want looking into. The mod team will investigate and hopefully nothing untoward is occurring.

Answer (score 6):

As @TheLethalCarrot has already pointed out, asking about the *person* behind the questions is a bit of a no-no. We can, however, address the questions themselves.

Ten questions were asked. A couple were dupes and can be largely disregarded because it's possible that OP didn't see the notifications. Of those that remain, four are actually pretty good and will probably attract more upvotes if they prove to be answerable.

- [How did Wall-E keep his memory of Eve when he was rebuilt?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/252596/how-did-wall-e-keep-his-memory-of-eve-when-he-was-rebuilt) - +8*
- [When EVE shut down, how did Wall-E's electronics turn off?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/252736/when-eve-shut-down-how-did-wall-es-electronics-turn-off) +2
- [How will each of Axiom's robots in Wall•E (besides AUTO, EVE, and WALL•E) be used on Earth?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/252608/how-will-each-of-axioms-robots-in-wall-e-besides-auto-eve-and-wall-e-be-use) +1
- [When EVE is flying, why does her blue trails only appear in space?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253268/when-eve-is-flying-why-does-her-blue-trails-only-appear-in-space) +1

Two I feel were unfairly downvoted and are now heading into positive territory, having been edited into better shape.

- [How did the Wall-As exit the Axiom after landing?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253341/how-did-the-wall-as-exit-the-axiom-after-landing) - +2*
- [Why can't EVE get out of uncompressed garbage?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253367/why-cant-eve-get-out-of-uncompressed-garbage) +2*

And yes, a couple of them were a bit crap, but that's to be expected from a brand new user asking a bunch of questions.

---

*<sub><sup>ignoring downvotes</sup></sub>

Comment: Isn't it disingenuous to ignore downvotes? I'm not saying they're necessarily deserved but they're still relevant.

Comment: @RogueJedi - I've ignored them because the same few people appear to have been involved in downvoting several of their questions. Also, I feel that they are (in their current configuration) unworthy of downvote and likely to end up in positive territory

Comment: @RogueJedi - Down votes are outliers in a system that we can't correct, so yes, ignore them.

Comment: @Valorum I downvoted two of them because I thought they were bad - based on a false premise or a trivial misunderstanding. I hadn't noticed this was all the same user.

Comment: @OrangeDog - I thought [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253341/how-did-the-wall-as-exit-the-axiom-after-landing), in particular, was quite unfairly downvoted. Several users made erroneous comments (that they've still not removed) about the Wall-A's being on treads when a ten second google revealed that they're on rails, then downvoted based on that.